# Wordpress site complains about "strict standards"

Tags: wordpress

Below is my error:

**Strict Standards: Declaration of WP_Scripts::set_group() should be compatible with that of WP_Dependencies::set_group() in C:\inetpub\vhosts\strykerradios.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php on line 220**

**Below is my website :**
http://www.strykerradios.com/wordpress/

Please help to fix this, so that I can get my site back.

Comment: How did you fix this? Do you remember?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your PHP is outdated. Try to update to the newest version.